# how to convert java interface code to kotlin code?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to convert some java code to kotlin.
this is my code wanna convert.

```
/*Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface*/
    GetDataService service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetDataService.class);
```

And this is class i made.

```
class RetrofitClientInstance {

    var retrofit: Retrofit?=null
    var BASE_URL = "10.80.7.30:3000"

     fun getRetrofitInstnace() :Retrofit {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }
        return retrofit!!
    }

}

interface MovieService {

    @GET("/movie/:id/script")
    fun getCurrentMovieData(
        @Path("id") id : Int
    ) : Call<Movie>

    @GET("/movie/script")
    fun getMoviesData() : Call<List<Movie>>
}
```

Please help me anytime!!!!!

Comment: Improve formatting

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Android Studio, you can just:

- Configure Kotlin in project
- Right-click on `.java` file and select 'Convert Java File to Kotlin File'

If you copy paste the Java snippet into .kt file, it will also ask you if you want to convert it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your above java code should be like the following.

```
var service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetDataService::class.java)
```